# Ubuntu 20.04 syslog warnings on suspend

Tags: suspend, dell, 20.04, systemd, iwlwifi

Recently I've noticed that when I suspend my laptop it shows what I think to be a systemd window (could be a TTY, I'm not sure)- juts a black screen with a coursor flickering. The problem is that after returning from suspend mode it shows there some warnings related to wifi. The wifi itself is working fine and the warning is not important one. However this is a little annoying as if you suspend it several times per day you can see a column of text before the login screen pops-up.
I've never see that behavior before with 18.04. Does someone know if this is normal? Is it possible to "skip" this screen?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That actually was syslog kernel messages and there's a deafult way to disable them to prevent spamming your console and apearing each time before you login, for example.

You just need to modify this file `/etc/sysctl.conf`doing the following:

```
    # Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
      kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3
```

The line is commented by default. Removing the comment stops low-level messages from appearing in the console, e.g. console blinking before login screen appears as happens when laptop returns from suspend mode.
The message are perfectly available via dmesg or logged in journalctl so you can check them late if you need. The high-level messages will still appear.

That makes it estetically better as I do not want to see a lot of warning spam from my wifi each time I suspend my laptop. Besides I have a habit to check error log from tiem to time, so it works fine for me.

Found the solution there [How to stop kernel messages from flooding my console?](https://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console/793692#793692)